# Writing Robot Dynamics Based Control in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please excuse me if my question is too basic.
I have gone through ROS control package and moveit etc. But, I want to test my own controller. My question is simple. How can I do this? For example, I want to write my controller like

```
M(q)q_ddot + C(q,q_dot)q_dot +G(q) = tau
```

and so I design my control law "tau" as

```
tau = M^-1(a_q) + C(q,q_dot)q_dot + G(q)
```

Can anyone guide me for the steps I should take? I have modeled my robot in ROS using URDF etc. Now, I want to evaluate my own control law.

I have been following book Learning ROS for robotics programming and Mastering ROS for robotics programming but I could not understand this. Your words will be highly appreciable. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246767/writing-robot-dynamics-based-control-in-ros/) by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-10-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2016-10-30**:
With ROS control you should have a controller for each joint, so you would apply the results of tau to each joint. Do you already have the control law written?

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-10-30**:
Thanks. I have simulated this in Matlab but I don't know how to do it in ROS. It will be great if you could guide me in steps the procedure to do that. It will be highly appreciated.

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-10-31**:
Thank you so much for your comment. I am going to follow your link thoroughly. Please, put your link in the answer so that I may accept it. It was a great tutorial and it was exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to create a joint effort controller for each actuated joint. Then you send a force/torque command to the controllers based on your control law computation. [Here](https://github.com/JoshMarino/gazebo_and_ros_control#Torque%20Control) is a tutorial I wrote a little while back for it.

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4